# Error using 'imhist' in MATLAB 2014

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am trying to use imhist to display the histogram of a uint8 .jpg, however I am getting this error:

> Error using imhist Expected input number 1, I or X, to be
>   two-dimensional.
>
> Error in imhist>parse_inputs (line 278) validateattributes(a,
>   {'double','uint8','int8','logical','uint16','int16','single','uint32',
>   'int32'}, ...
>
> Error in imhist (line 60) [a, n, isScaled, top, map] =
>   parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Here is my image information:

> whos f   Name         Size                   Bytes  Class
>   Attributes
>
> f         2988x5312x3            47616768  uint8

Do I need to convert my image to another data class? I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cause of error is because your image is RGB and imhist does not deal with that. To work around this you can either use a single channel:

```
imhist(YourImage(:,:,Channel));
```

or convert from RGB to grayscale:

```
imhist(rgb2gray(YourImage));
```

That should work fine now.

Comment: +1 - Yup... a lot of people make the mistake of supplying a colour image to `imhist`.  Very nice :)

Comment: @rayryeng I wonder what they expect to obtain from that... a 4D graph? :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - hahahaha that made me laugh.  Thank you